# Chrome 39 XSLTProcessor returns null if input is in HTML namespace and attribute value contains JS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xslt

Long-story-short, I'm developing a Chrome extension that applies an XSL transformation to the DOM of a webpage. This works, except in a very specific case; if an attribute value contains inline Javascript (i.e. begins with the string "javascript:") and the remainder of that value contains a less-than symbol even when it is properly escaped.

Example - Working code:

```
xml = '\
  <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">\
    <a href="javascript:foo bar">my link</a>\
  </p>';

xsl = '<?xml version="1.0"?>\
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">\
  <xsl:output version="1.0" method="xml" />\
  </xsl:stylesheet>';

parse = new DOMParser();
xmlDOM = parse.parseFromString(xml, 'text/xml');
xslDOM = parse.parseFromString(xsl, 'text/xml');

xsltProc = new XSLTProcessor();
xsltProc.importStylesheet(xslDOM);
result = xsltProc.transformToFragment(xmlDOM, document);
```

The above example is very minimal, so the value of `result` is a very simple DOM fragment, but it isn't null, so the transformation has been successful.

If we now add an encoded less-than sign into the value of a@href in the input XML:

```
    <a href="javascript:foo &lt;bar">my link</a>\
```

...this will cause the transformation to fail and `result` will be null.

The trigger for this problem is very specific. The attribute containing the "javascript:" prefix and less-than symbol must be in a [X]HTML namespace, and only attributes that normally contain URLs are affected, so in addition to a@href, iframe@src, script@src and img@src are all affected.

This problem doesn't happen if the value isn't prefixed "javascript:".

This problem also doesn't seem to occur in the command line `xsltproc` or in Firefox.

So my question is simply: Why does this happen?

And I suppose an obvious follow-up questionette would be, does this allow Javascript to be embedded and executed in XSL.

And just in case anyone is wondering... yes, it was *very* hard to figure out what was triggering this! :D

Comment: In your sample the attribute is in no namespace, it is an attribute of an `a` element being in the XHTML namespace but the attribute itself is certainly in no namespace. So I don't understand why you say "The attribute ... must be in a [X]HTML namespace".

Comment: I created http://jsfiddle.net/rtheurpx/, can confirm it does not work in Chrome 39. I think this is a bug in Chrome, the `transformToFragment` should always return a document fragment and not null, unless of course the transformation throws an error, but Chrome does not display one, only the final `appendChild` on the fragment gives an error. I also created http://jsfiddle.net/20ye5o2e/2/ where at least the transformation works, although Chrome does not display the result of the javascript href when clicking the link.

Comment: Finally http://jsfiddle.net/k5nfejt9/ shows that Chrome does not even display the result of a `javascript:` href when clicking such a link in static HTML.

Comment: Re namespace, yeah you're right. What I _meant_ was that the parent has to be in an HTML namespace. So in my example, if we changed the xmlns declaration in the input XML to "http://foobar", then the transformation would be successful, i.e. work as expected.

Comment: Re your examples http://jsfiddle.net/rtheurpx/ and http://jsfiddle.net/20ye5o2e/2/ this confirms the problem. It seems (from my limited testing) that the value of the attribute doesn't matter (as expected... it's just a text node) but the bug will only be triggered if the value matches a regexp /^\s*javascript:.*</i. I wouldn't _expect_ it to be attempting to execute the JS, but the fact the bug is triggered in a very specific case implies (to me at least) that it might be trying to. Still strange how it requires a less-than symbol to fail though!

Comment: I don't think the Javascript in the link is executed during the XSLT transformation, that does not make sense to me. For what it's worth, I have opened http://jsfiddle.net/rtheurpx/ in Chrome and used the menu to report a problem to Google, explaining the problem with transformToFragment not returning a document fragment node, also linking to this stackoverflow question.

Comment: I'll accept "it's a bug" as the answer to my question then -- thanks Martin! :D (not sure how I give you points for this... do you need to post an actual answer rather than a comment?)